# Date time conversion results in FORG0001 Invalid dateTime value - XSLT 3.0

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

Resources:

```
Java 1.8
Saxon-HE-10.3
XSLT3.0
```

I am merging 2 XML files and want to do date manipulation in the merged output file xml.

1. I am taking the 2 files as input using java and generate the merged xml - This works fine.
2. Now, I added the date manipulation in the xsl after the merging operation.
3. Date Manipulation - convert the given date to epoch/milliseconds

Date format which comes with the input file

```
<PROP NAME="START_DATE">
<PVAL>16-Aug-2018</PVAL>
</PROP>
```

The issue is when I try to convert the given date to dateTime or convert to epoch, I get the below error on compilation.

```
Error at char 10 in expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 60 column 105 of CASTransform.xsl:   FORG0001  Invalid dateTime value "/01--20T00:00:00" (Non-numeric year component) at template reformat-date on line 55 of CASTransform.xsl:
 invoked by xsl:call-template at file:/home/Merger/scripts/CASTransform.xsl#50 In template rule with match="element(Q{}RECORDS)/element(Q{}RECORD)/element(Q{}PROP)[(Q{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string(data(attribute::attribute(Q{}NAME)))) eq "START_DATE"]/element(Q{}PVAL)" on line 48 of CASTransform.xsl
 invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:/home/Merger/scripts/CASTransform.xsl#45 In template rule with match="(element()|(text()|(comment()|processing-instruction())))" on line 43 of CASTransform.xsl
 invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:/home/Merger/scripts/CASTransform.xsl#35 at template main on line 14 of CASTransform.xsl: Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Invalid dateTime value "/01--20T00:00:00" (Non-numeric year component)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.Xslt30Transformer.callTemplate(Xslt30Transformer.java:488)
```

XSL Code

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
        xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
        <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:param name="mapData"/>
        <xsl:template match="/" name="main">
            <RECORDS>
                <xsl:variable name="file1" select="map:get($mapData, '1')" />
                <xsl:variable name="input-doc1" as="document-node()" select="doc($file1)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="file2" select="map:get($mapData, '2')" />
                <xsl:variable name="input-doc2" as="document-node()" select="doc($file2)"/>
                <xsl:merge>
                    <xsl:merge-source name="doc1" select="$input-doc1/RECORDS/RECORD">
                        <xsl:merge-key select="PROP[@NAME = 'Id']/PVAL"></xsl:merge-key>
                    </xsl:merge-source>
                    <xsl:merge-source name="doc2" select="$input-doc2/RECORDS/RECORD">
                        <xsl:merge-key select="PROP[@NAME = 'Id']/PVAL"></xsl:merge-key>
                    </xsl:merge-source>
                    <xsl:merge-action>
                        <xsl:if test="current-merge-group('doc1')">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="*, current-merge-group('doc2')/(* except PROP[@NAME = 'Id'])"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:merge-action>
                </xsl:merge>
            </RECORDS>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="RECORDS/RECORD/PROP[@NAME = 'START_DATE']/PVAL | RECORDS/RECORD/PROP[@NAME = 'END_DATE']/PVAL">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:call-template name="reformat-date">
                <xsl:with-param name="date" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="reformat-date">
        <xsl:param name="date" />
        <xsl:variable name="dd" select="substring($date,1,2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="mmm" select="upper-case(substring($date,4,3))" />
        <xsl:variable name="yyyy" select="substring($date,8,4)" />
        <xsl:variable name="mmm">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'JAN'">01</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'FEB'">02</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'MAR'">03</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'APR'">04</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'MAY'">05</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'JUN'">06</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'JUL'">07</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'AUG'">08</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'SEP'">09</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'OCT'">10</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'NOV'">11</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'DEC'">12</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="temp1" as="xs:string" select="string-join(($yyyy,$mmm,$dd),'-')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$temp1" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSL code works perfectly fine and the $temp1 gives proper date like 2018-08-16.

Now, when I try to convert this to dateTime variable I get the mentioned compilation error.

Code which gives error:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp2" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(concat($temp1,'T00:00:00'))"/>
```

and tried this as well :

```
<xsl:value-of select="floor((xs:dateTime(concat($temp1,'T00:00:00')) - xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')) "/>
```

Requesting your help as this is my first XSL project.

Full Stacktrace:

```
 Error at char 10 in expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 60 column 105 of CASTransform.xsl:
      FORG0001  Invalid dateTime value "/01--20T00:00:00" (Non-numeric year component)
    at template reformat-date on line 55 of CASTransform.xsl:
         invoked by xsl:call-template at file:/home/Merger/scripts/CASTransform.xsl#50
      In template rule with match="element(Q{}RECORDS)/element(Q{}RECORD)/element(Q{}PROP)[(Q{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string(data(attribute::attribute(Q{}NAME)))) eq "START_DATE"]/element(Q{}PVAL)" on line 48 of CASTransform.xsl
         invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:/home/Merger/scripts/CASTransform.xsl#45
      In template rule with match="(element()|(text()|(comment()|processing-instruction())))" on line 43 of CASTransform.xsl
         invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:/home/Merger/scripts/CASTransform.xsl#35
    at template main on line 14 of CASTransform.xsl:
    Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Invalid dateTime value "/01--20T00:00:00" (Non-numeric year component)
            at net.sf.saxon.s9api.Xslt30Transformer.callTemplate(Xslt30Transformer.java:488)
            at com.tracer.Merger.CASExportInput.trans(CASExportInput.java:38)
            at com.tracer.Merger.CASExportInput.main(CASExportInput.java:58)
    Caused by: ValidationException: Invalid dateTime value "/01--20T00:00:00" (Non-numeric year component)
            at net.sf.saxon.type.ValidationFailure.makeException(ValidationFailure.java:406)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.CastExpression.doCast(CastExpression.java:385)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.CastExpression.evaluateItem(CastExpression.java:402)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.CastExpression.evaluateItem(CastExpression.java:30)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression.iterate(Expression.java:872)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.AtomicSequenceConverter.iterate(AtomicSequenceConverter.java:304)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression.process(Expression.java:949)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ValueOf.processLeavingTail(ValueOf.java:340)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:746)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:752)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NamedTemplate.expand(NamedTemplate.java:264)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.CallTemplate$CallTemplatePackage.processLeavingTail(CallTemplate.java:549)
            at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:478)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:351)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.process(ApplyTemplates.java:285)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Copy.processLeavingTail(Copy.java:429)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:384)
            at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:568)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:351)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.process(ApplyTemplates.java:285)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Copy.processLeavingTail(Copy.java:429)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:142)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionTool.getIteratorFromProcessMethod(ExpressionTool.java:643)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.iterate(Instruction.java:374)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.iterate(Choose.java:1019)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.MergeInstr.lambda$iterate$0(MergeInstr.java:543)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.ContextMappingIterator.next(ContextMappingIterator.java:61)
            at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:135)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.MergeInstr.processLeavingTail(MergeInstr.java:823)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:142)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.process(LetExpression.java:625)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:298)
            at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NamedTemplate.expand(NamedTemplate.java:264)
            at net.sf.saxon.trans.XsltController.callTemplate(XsltController.java:850)
            at net.sf.saxon.s9api.Xslt30Transformer.callTemplate(Xslt30Transformer.java:480)
            ... 2 more
```

Java code which serves the Input files :

```
package com.tracer.Merger.CASMerger;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api. * ;

public class CASExportInput {
  public static void trans(String XSLFile, String File1, String File2, String OutputFileName, String OutputFilePath) throws SaxonApiException {
    String MergedFile = OutputFilePath.concat(OutputFileName);

    Processor processor = new Processor(false);
    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
    XsltExecutable exp = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new File(XSLFile)));
    Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(new File(MergedFile));
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
    Xslt30Transformer trans = exp.load30();

    Map < String,
    String > mapData = new HashMap < String,
    String > ();
    mapData.put("1", File1);
    mapData.put("2", File2);
    HashMap < QName,
    XdmValue > parameters = new HashMap < >();
    parameters.put(new QName("mapData"), XdmMap.makeMap(mapData));
    trans.setStylesheetParameters(parameters);

    trans.callTemplate(new QName("main"), out);
    System.out.println("Output written to : " + MergedFile);

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws SaxonApiException {

    if (args.length < 3) System.out.println("\nPlease check if you have entered arguments properly...");
    String XSLFile = args[0].toString().trim();
    String File1 = args[1].toString().trim();
    String File2 = args[2].toString().trim();
    String FileName1 = File1.substring(File1.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, File1.length() - 4);
    String FileName2 = File2.substring(File2.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, File2.length() - 4);
    String OutputFilePath = File1.substring(0, File1.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    String OutputFileName = FileName1.concat("-" + FileName2 + ".xml");
    trans(XSLFile, File1, File2, OutputFileName, OutputFilePath);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear where the code fails, if you have a format `16-Aug-2018` I wonder what that `tokenize(., ' ')` is meant to achieve. Anyway, you have inserted a complete, minimal XSLT example, you can edit your question and show two minimal but complete samples that allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry! I uploaded one of my test code with tokenize. Please ignore that - I have updated the code. Also, that is my complete xsl as of now. To reproduce the problem, adding <xsl:variable name="temp2" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(concat($temp1,'T00:00:00'))"/>  after  <xsl:value-of select="$temp1" /> will throw compilation error.

Comment: Well, show us minimal but complete input sample data we can use to reproduce the error, I don't get one with your code at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVrr.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks a lot for looking into it. Yes, as you mentioned I am not able to reproduce that compilation error in online compilers as you shared. But when I try to run the same in eclipse or any other env I am getting these compilation errors. I have added a full stacktrace of the error which I got when I tried to run it in one of my linux env.

Comment: I doubt it is the stack trace that allows us to explain it, I guess some of your input data is different so you need to show minimal but complete input samples giving the error

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have added the java code as well. I tried with actual data in online compiler you shared and it works fine as well

Comment: So your code fails with an input that contains nothing but the sample data `<PVAL>16-Aug-2018</PVAL>` shown? Or are you finally able to show us the data that fails?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried to upload some realtime data and it works fine in online compiler. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4ut/7

I am not able to reproduce this issue in online compiler. But, while trying to transform the xml via java throws that error. 

Also, please note that the issue happens only when I try to cast the date to dateTime on this line <xsl:variable name="temp2" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(concat($temp1,'T00:00:00'))"/> and that too happens when i compile it locally using java. Sample xml file - https://gofile.io/d/xZA5pc

Comment: I used the samples you have put online in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4ut/7 and run them through Saxon HE 10.3 from the command line and it doesn't give any error. Try to provide minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. The XSLT code looks fine for the sample format you have presented, if you get an error I still assume that is because you feed some data in a different format.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks a ton for spending your time on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was. But, I uninstalled and re-installed Java 1.8 and the issue got fixed. No changes were done in the xsl or java code.